# CSS3 buttons that move the frame - how to fix this in IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, css, animation, label

I've got this problem with IE (surprise, surprise). I have a frame. Inside, I have a table three times as wide, but 2/3 is not visible thanks to overflow: hidden. At the start, only the middle section is visible.

Now this middle section has two labels posing as buttons. They are a part od checkboxes that are outside the table. Their job is to make the table move right or left, displaying the appropriate part of the table. Everything is made in CSS3 and works great in Firefox, pretty good in Chrome (but  can fix that one), but there is no reaction in IE, even in version 10.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: We _could_ help you, but you'd have to show your code first.

Comment: Dammit, I left my files at home, and I'm at work :( . Oh well, I'll repost it after I come back. Thanks for replies though.